# what is E/SPRDHWComposer and [is_hide_jerusalem]

Tags: android, cordova, android-logcat

```
E/SPRDHWComposer(190): GSP_Proccess L1054,mGSPAddrType2,layer0_en0,layer0format0
```

01-31

I saw this error displaying non stop at the logcat while running my own android app (a media playing app ) , any idea what causes it ?

```
 E/juan(684): getBoolean szkey = [is_hide_jerusalem]
```

and I saw the above at logcat each time I install or uninstall any app from my android phone . could it be triggered by some kind of malware ?